# Cin not pausing for (is ignoring) user input

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When the code is run the `cin` in the `FtoC()` function is ignored and instead the value of `ctemp` is defaulted to `0`. I have gotten the code running desirably using other code (different loop) but I would really like to understand the mechanism for this error and get this way of doing it to work.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void threeint();
void FtoC();

int main()
{  
    threeint();
    FtoC();
    return 0;
}

void FtoC()

{
    double ctemp = 0, ftemp = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the temperature in Celsius which you would like to be\
            converted to Fharenheit." << endl;

    cin >> ctemp;

    ftemp = ((ctemp * (9 / 5)) + 35);

    cout << ctemp << " degrees celsius is " << ftemp << " in fahrenheit" << endl;
}


void threeint()
{
    int x = 0, bigint = 0, smlint = INT_MAX, avgint = 0, index = 0;

    cout << "Input as many integers as you like and finalise by entering any
             non-integer input" << endl;

    while (cin >> x)
    {
    if (x > bigint)
        bigint = x;
    if (x < smlint)
        smlint = x;

    ++index;
    avgint += x;
    }

cout << "The largest integer is " << bigint << ".\t" << "The smallest 
         integer is " << smlint << ".\t";

cout << "The average of all input is " << (avgint / index) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You never check `cin`'s state, if a `double` or `int` extraction failed.

Comment: Unrelated but `(9 / 5)` won't do what you think it does. (Hint: the result of that is exactly 1, if that surprises you, [see here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html))

Answer (score 1):

After a "bad read" your `cin` is in a bad-input state. You should skip the bad input and clear its flags before re-attempting a read

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Skip bad input
```

Answer (score 0):

I will begin by answering your question. The reason why your cin does not wait for input is because cin is not reset to accept a new value after bad input (like entering a letter for your input). To overcome this, you have to clear the input and ignore any bad input entered. This can be done by adding the following lines to your program:

```
 cin.clear(); // clears cin error flags
 cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignores any invalid input entered
```

> The ios::clear sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags. The current value of the flags is overwritten: All bits are replaced by those in state; If state is goodbit (which is zero) all error flags are cleared.

This was directly quoted from [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/); for cin.clear().

> cin.ignore() Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to delim. The function also stops extracting characters if the end-of-file is reached. If this is reached prematurely (before either extracting n characters or finding delim), the function sets the eofbit flag.

This was directly quoted from [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/?kw=cin.ignore); for cin.ignore().

These 2 quotes give an in-depth analysis, along with the provided link, of how the 2 functions work.

---

A couple of other things to point out in your program are:

**Firstly**, when you do 9/5, you are intending for the value to be 1.8 . However, since you are dividing two integer values, the compiler will keep the end result as na int; therefore, 9/5=1 in your code. To overcome this issue, the divident or divisor of your division operation needs to be of type float. The easiest and simplest way to do this is to do 9.0 / 5, or 9 / 5.0. This way, the compiler knows that you want to have the end result as a floating point value. You can also use casting, however, adding a decimal point is way easier and simpler.

**Secondly**, and I am not sure whether this mistake is only in the code you have posted here or not since you say yours compiles perfectly, but some of your string literals in your cout statements are not enclosed properly by apostrophes, at least in the code you have posted here. An examply is this line fom your code:

```
 cout << "The largest integer is " << bigint << ".\t" << "The smallest 
     integer is " << smlint << ".\t";
```

God luck!