# How can I show "Wrong Value" when i put negative numbers?

Tags: c++, function, math

I'm new to coding, but I think my code is wrong but it works. Can you help me fix the code to display the "Wrong Value" if the user puts any negative numbers or letters? any suggestions and what is the problem with my code so I can learn more? I think this is a function code that performs a specific task, here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a();
int b();

main ()
{
    a();
    b();


    return 0;
}
int a()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Enter 1st number: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Enter 2nd number: ";
    cin >> y;

    if (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 1) 
    cout << "The numbers are odd" << endl;

    else if (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0)
    cout << "The numbers are even" << endl;

}
int b()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    if (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 0)
    cout << "1st is odd, 2nd is even" << endl;

    else if (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 1)
    cout << "1st is even, 2nd is odd" << endl;

}
```

How can I show "Wrong Value" if the user puts any negative numbers or letters?

Comment: How would you write an `if` statement to check for negative numbers?  You must know that much.  Have you tried entering letters to see what happens?

Comment: By the way, `x` and `y` in your function `b` are totally different from the `x` and `y` in your function `a`.  In function `b`, those values will be random memory.  What you should do is do your inputs in `main` and pass both values to the functions.

Comment: the problem is if i put a letter, the result look like this

Enter 1st number: a
Enter 2nd number: The numbers are even

Comment: can you show more about that main thing?

Comment: @Amimir *"the problem is if i put a letter, the result look like this [...]"* -- This means that your **example** code should do nothing more than ask for and read two numbers. Period. No trying to analyze the result, because you are not getting a result. Stop as soon as the error can be seen. `int main() { int x; int y;

cout << "Enter 1st number: ";
cin >> x;

cout << "Enter 2nd number: ";
cin >> y;
cout << "Did you enter a second number?\n";
}` That's enough to demonstrate that the program is not waiting for the second number to be entered, isn't it?

Comment: *"How can I show 'Wrong Value' if the user puts any negative numbers or letters?"* -- This looks suspiciously similar to [How to validate user input a number and the number greater than 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7594273), except that other question is really asking only the latter. So oddly, your title matches that question, while that question's title matches yours. *Other related Q&A: [What happens when you cin>> letter to int variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407771) and [Cin not pausing for (is ignoring) user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42557607)*

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've fixed a number of things here.  I ask for the input in `main`, and pass the values to `a` and `b`.  I changed the return types of `a` and `b` to `void`, since they don't return anything.  I added code to check for negative values, and for incorrect inputs.  When you type characters and cin is expecting digits, what happens is that the input remains in the buffer and the `fail` bit gets set.  Note that I don't retry the input in that case -- that's an exercise left for the reader.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void a(int x, int y);
void b(int x, int y);

int main ()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Enter 1st number: ";
    cin >> x;

    if( cin.fail() || x < 0 )
    {
        cout << "Wrong Value\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Enter 2nd number: ";
    cin >> y;

    if( cin.fail() || y < 0 )
    {
        cout << "Wrong Value\n";
        return -2;
    }

    a(x,y);
    b(x,y);

    return 0;
}

void a(int x, int y)
{
    if (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 1) 
    cout << "The numbers are odd" << endl;

    else if (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 0)
    cout << "The numbers are even" << endl;
}

void b(int x, int y)
{
    if (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 0)
    cout << "1st is odd, 2nd is even" << endl;

    else if (x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 1)
    cout << "1st is even, 2nd is odd" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ g++ -o x x.cpp
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ ./x
Enter 1st number: ff
Wrong Value
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ ./x
Enter 1st number: -9
Wrong Value
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$
```